# Do we need to write code to sort a gridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've read some articles online where they say you just need to set the "AllowSorting" property to true, while there are others that have code written in the Sorting event. So my question is- To sort a gridviwe in ASP.NET, do we need to write any code in the sorting event or does setting "AllowSorting" to true enable the sorting?

Also, will anything change if I set my datasource programmatically as opposed to setting it directly as a SqlDataSource in the .aspx file itself?

Comment: That depends on what you're using as datasource. If you use a declarative datasource control like SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource you're done, otherwise you need to write the code yourself.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'd say that's an answer. You should post it as so and get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>As requested, my comment as answer:</sub>

That depends on what you're using as `DataSource`. If you use a declarative datasource control like `SqlDataSource` or `ObjectDataSource` you're done, otherwise you need to write the code yourself.

Comment: After just going thru a lot of Grid creation and modification, if you plan on doing lots of stuff in your grid, don't use a datasource object, bind in the code behind.  Yes, the dataobjects handle a lot of stuff for you on the Grids, but it also puts lots of restrictions on what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently accomplished what you're asking by using something along the following lines:

```
DataTable dt = YourOwnWayOfCreatingADataTable();
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "ColumnNameToSort"; // You can append ASC or DESC to this
gridView1.DataSource = dt;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

I hope that helps you out.  Obviously, this is sorting the results before you display them, but you can sort again by changing the .Sort property and rebinding.  If you need something more specific or multiple columns, this may not work.